# Find difference line by line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a program which stores some data in two files stored in separate folders. **/Path_1/File A** and **/Path_2/File B**.

Now I need to compare those two files line by line for any differences. If any difference noted, I need to capture that and stored in a separate file or print it on the screen.

I tried using comm,diff and join. But none of them worked so far. Appreciate any help.

Sample file looks like following.

- 124 days
- 3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64
- /dev/mapper/vg_sda-lv_root          ext4
- devtmpfs                            devtmpfs

In other file number of days and kernel version can be differ. I only need to capture that while running a script.

I tried **diff -y -W 120 Source/File   Destination/File** , **comm File1 File2**

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that comm didn't worked for me. What I need is at the moment when difference found that difference should only capture.

Comment: please add sample input files, expected output and command you tried which didn't work to question..

Comment: your question is still not clear, at least for me.. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.. instead of words, add both input files and give the expected output explicitly.. the command you have given doesn't even look valid.. could you also paste the output exactly as seen on your terminal?

Comment: and does this command `diff --suppress-common-lines -y -W 120 /Path_1/File_A /Path_1/File_B` work for you?

Comment: none of above worked. I came up with another approach. 
for i in $BASE_DIR_PRE/*; do

        while read line
                do

                grep $line $BASE_DIR_POST/${i##*/}

                done < $i

done

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
diff --suppress-common-lines /path_1/file_a /path_2/file_b > output
```

Where `--suppress-common-lines` does:

> "do not output common lines"